# PyTorch data loading from multiple different-sized datasets

Tags: python, pytorch

I have multiple datasets, each with a different number of images (and different image dimensions) in it. In the training loop I want to load a batch of images randomly from among all the datasets but so that each batch only contains images from a single dataset. For example, I have datasets A, B, C, D and each has images 01.jpg, 02.jpg, … n.jpg (where n depends on the dataset), and let’s say the batch size is 3. In the first loaded batch, for example, I may get images [B/02.jpg, B/06.jpg, B/12.jpg], in the next batch [D/01.jpg, D/05.jpg, D/12.jpg], etc.

So far I have considered the following:

1. Use a different DataLoader for each dataset, e.g. dataloaderA, dataloaderB, etc., and then in each training loop randomly select one of the dataloaders and get a batch from it. However, this will require a for loop and for large number of datasets it would be very slow since it can’t be split among workers to do it in parallel.
2. Use a single DataLoader with all of the images from all datasets together but with a custom collate_fn which will create a batch using only images from the same dataset. (I’m not sure how exactly to go about this.)
3. I have looked at the ConcatDataset class but from its source code it looks like if I use it and try getting a new batch the images in it will be mixed up from among different datasets which I don’t want.

What would be the best way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ConcatDataset`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.ConcatDataset), and provide a `batch_sampler` to [`DataLoader`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#torch.utils.data.DataLoader).

```
concat_dataset = ConcatDataset((dataset1, dataset2))
```

`ConcatDataset.comulative_sizes` will give you the boundaries between each dataset you have:

```
ds_indices = concat_dataset.cumulative_sizes
```

Now, you can use `ds_indices` to create a batch sampler. See [the source for `BatchSampler`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/utils/data/sampler.html#BatchSampler) for reference. Your batch sampler just has to return a list with N random indices that will respect the `ds_indices` boundaries. This will guarantee that your batches will have elements from the same dataset.

Comment: Could you share some info on how I could use this custom BatchSampler in the distributed setting? I typically use the `sampler` arg in DataLoader and provide a DistributedSampler object to it, but now I wouldn't be able to do that any more because the `batch_sampler` arg is mutually exclusive from the `sampler` arg.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just wanted to point out that, as @Ricky just said, when building a `DataLoader` using a custom BatchSampler, one should not use the `sampler`, but the `batch_sampler` argument instead. I was getting `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'` and didn't know where it came from until I did the change